# Custom route element not working in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.1. Here's the deal...

I want an url in this format:

```
http://mysite.com/[username]/
```

Where `[username]` can be dynamic and calls the "Users" controller already implemented.

Here's the route defined in routes.php:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:username',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('username'),
        'username' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][/-_.]+'
    ));
```

If I try to reach http://mysite.com/testuser this error is shown:

```
"Missing Controller
Error: testuserController could not be found."
```

Here's my entire routes.php file:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Routes configuration
 *
 * In this file, you set up routes to your controllers and their actions.
 * Routes are very important mechanism that allows you to freely connect
 * different urls to chosen controllers and their actions (functions).
 *
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Config
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */

    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));

    Router::connect(
    '/:username',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('username'),
        'username' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][/-_.]+'
    ));

/**
 * Load all plugin routes.  See the CakePlugin documentation on 
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
    CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

I've tried with something like this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/users/:username',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('username'),
        'username' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][/-_.]+'
    ));
```

and this way it worked...! And then I can get with: $this->request->params['pass'][0]

So, now it's the question: Why it doesn't work in the first level of the path (domain.com/:nickname)?

Comment: Can you please post your full routes file?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to have `:username` in there, as its a parameter not a `:controller` or `:action` might have to check the manual, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration

Comment: @DavidYell, I was trying to do something with the route elements: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements but I'm not sure if I can have this "element" right after the domain without specify any controller or action... Reading the docs it's possible to do this, but isn't working...

Comment: @Line have you tried with a named parameter pair? /username:davidyell then `$this->request->params['named']['username']`

Comment: I've tried with something like this: domain.com/users/:nickname and this way it worked... And then I get with: $this->request->params['pass'][0] (I have to declare on the Router that I'm passing this forward). So, now it's the question: Why it doesn't work in the first level of the path (domain.com/:nickname)? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'actionName'));
```

And then in your UsersController if you have

```
public function foo($username){
   ...
}
```

$username will contain the username from the URL